# How to make a View to fill the space between two views?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to layout my views in the following way: `[Button] [SomeView] [Button]`. I want to set specific sizes for buttons (in mm), and then have the `SomeView` fill the remaining space between them.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you could set the layout:weight of the [SomeView] to 1 and put all of these views in a linearlayout. Hope it works!

Comment: Wow. I was sure that I had tried this and it hadn't worked, but it seems that this works in fact. :)